# UEFI Question: why does Ubuntu 15.10 installer ask where to put bootloader?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubunt 15.10 to boot via UEFI alongside Window 10. At https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI, I see:

> Note that in a UEFI-mode installation, Ubuntu will not ask you where to install the boot loader. If it does, or if it complains about the lack of a BIOS Boot Partition, you've probably accidentally booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

Now, I'm pretty sure I've booted the installer image with UEFI (e.g. `/sys/firmware/ef` exists, and "parted /dev/sda print" shows "Partition Table: gpt"). But the graphical installer, when I choose "Something Else" and set up my partitions as desired, the installer shows me an option to select where to install a bootloader (and fails, later on trying to install grub there).

Is there a known issue here?

Comment: Grub only installs to the ESP - efi system partition on sda. I have installed to sdb & external flash drives. Ubiquity even says it is installing grub to sdb, but it has always overwritten my /EFI/ubuntu in sda.  Only real difference is the grub.cfg in ESP, so I just copy that back from my backup. Post your partitions in first post above: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 1):

Because the developers didn't bother to hide the box in the ui if using UEFI.  Grub ignores the setting and always installs to the ESP anyhow.  Probably should file a papercut bug report, assuming there isn't one already... maybe someone will fix it.

Comment: That's helpful, but the installer subsequently fails, on trying to install grub there (if I choose the wrong value). So it seems like the value isn't just ignored.

Comment: @Bosh, then you must not be booting in EFI mode.  In EFI mode, you can choose anything you want and grub ignores it, since it installs to a directory rather than any device, even /dev/sda.  Note that even if you boot the install cd in UEFI mode, if you have an existing windows ( or other ) system that was installed in bios mode, then the installer will select the bios version of grub.  That could be what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "Something Else" option, you must identify your ESP as such. If you don't, Ubiquity won't know where to install GRUB. The installer *should* correctly identify your ESP if one already exists, but if not, you'll have to create one yourself. Make it a FAT32 partition of 550MB and tell the installer it's an ESP. (550MB because that's the smallest easily-remembered value that safely avoids common pitfalls at smaller sizes.)

If you're having problems with this, post the `parted -l` output that oldfred requested, a screen shot of the "Something Else" partitioning screen (or multiple screen shots, if necessary, to show all your partitions), and a screen shot of the error message you receive.

Comment: The installer sees my 512mb fat32 EFI partition, but doesn't let me say whether/where to mount it (no "mount point" option is displayed for that partition).

Comment: If it's identified as an EFI System Partition in the installer, it should be OK. (Older versions of Ubuntu called it an "EFI boot partition.") One more thing: You ***MUST*** disable the *Windows* "Fast Startup" option, as described [here.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) Failure to do so can cause filesystem damage and boot loader problems. Note that this feature is *not* the same as a firmware feature that often has a similar name.